# Excel Formula to Change Page Layout Orientation

Tags: excel, function, printing, excel-formula

**Question:**
Is there an Excel function to toggle the Page Layout Orientation between either Portrait or Landscape?

**Details:**
I have set up two named ranges, one called Tall, one called Wide.  I dynamically set the print area to be these named ranges using the cell link ($V$22) of a drop-down box by setting the named area "Print_Area" to refer to:

```
=CHOOSE('Sheet1'!$V$22,Tall,Wide)
```

This works well to set the print area.  I would also like to set the Page Layout -> Orientation to Portrait or Landscape to go along with my Tall or Wide print areas.

Is this possible?

Thank you, Doug

Comment: Not without VBA. You were able to accomplish the first due to **Print_Area** being a Defined Name whose definition could be rewritten; the same is not true for the `Worksheet.PageSetup.Orientation` property.

Comment: Yes, I'm hoping to keep macros/VBA out of this particular Worksheet.  So hoping there was a solution outside of VBA.  Thanks.